# How to use a Javascript file to refresh/reload a div from an HTML file?

Tags: html, node.js, json

I am using Node JS and have a JS file, which opens a connection to an API, works with the receving API data and then saves the changed data into a JSON file. Next I have an HTML file, which takes the data from the JSON file and puts it into a table. At the end I open the HTML file in my browser to look at the visualized table and its data.

What I would like to happen is, that the table (or more specific a DIV with an ID inside the table) from the HTML file refreshes itself, when the JSON data gets updated from the JS file. Kinda like a "live table/website", that I can watch change over time without the need to presh F5.

Instead of just opening the HTML locally, I have tried it by using the JS file and creating a connection with the file like this:

```js
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const browser = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './') {
        filePath = './Table.html';
    }

    var extname = String(path.extname(filePath)).toLowerCase();
    var mimeTypes = {
        '.html': 'text/html',
        '.css': 'text/css',
        '.png': 'image/png',
        '.js': 'text/javascript',
        '.json': 'application/json'
    };

    var contentType = mimeTypes[extname] || 'application/octet-stream';

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
        response.end(content, 'utf-8');
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

This creates a working connection and I am able to see it in the browser, but sadly it doesn't update itself like I wish. I thought about some kind of function, which gets called right after the JSON file got saved and tells the div to reload itself.
I also read about something like `window.onload`, `location.load()` or `getElementById()`, but I am not able to figure out the right way.

What can I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Websockets!

Though they might sound scary, it's very easy to get started with websockets in NodeJS, especially if you use Socket.io.

You will need two dependencies in your node application:

```
 "socket.io": "^4.1.3",
 "socketio-wildcard": "^2.0.0"
```

your HTML File:

```
  <script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Your CLIENT SIDE JavaScript file:

```
var socket = io();

socket.on("update", function (data) { //update can be any sort of string, treat it like an event name
  console.log(data);
  // the rest of the code to update the html
})
```

your NODE JS file:

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

// other code...

let io = new Server(server);
let activeConnections = {};

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) { 
  // 'connection' is a "magic" key
  
  // track the active connections
  activeConnections[socket.id] = socket;

  socket.on("disconnect", function () { 
    /* Not required, but you can add special handling here to prevent errors */ 
    delete activeConnections[socket.id];
  })

  socket.on("update", (data) => {  
    // Update is any sort of key
    console.log(data) 
  })
})


// Example with Express 
app.get('/some/api/call', function (req, res) {

 var data = // your API Processing here

 Object.keys(activeConnections).forEach((conn) => {
   conn.emit('update', data)
 }
 res.send(data); 
})
```

Finally, shameful self promotion, here's one of my "dead" side projects using websockets, because I'm sure I forgot some small detail, and this might help. https://github.com/Nhawdge/robert-quest

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I copied the two dependencies in my package.json and the script-line in my HTML file. I created an new js file for the "client side JS file" and copied the code into it. Then I copied the lines from "Node JS file" into my main js file. At the end I installed the socket.io module and tried a run. All is said was: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". What did I miss? Oh, and is there a way to write to you outside of stackoverflow, because the comment function just lets me write that much.